# No source available for cv::flann::Index::knnSearch()

Tags: opencv, sift, surf, descriptor, flann

I'm trying to implement Flann Index in OpenCV. Let me tell about my implementation step-by-step:

1) I extracted SURF features from images and concatenated all. Then saved descriptors and flann index like this:

```
FileStorage fs("descriptors.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs, "descriptors", descriptors);
flann_index_saved.save("tmp_twitter.fln");
```

2) I extracted SURF features from query image.

3) I loaded flann index like this:

```
FileStorage fsRead(yamlFile, FileStorage::READ);
Mat indexMat(Size(64, sampleSize), CV_32FC1);
fsRead["descriptors"] >> indexMat;
Index flann_index_loaded;
flann_index_loaded.load(indexMat, indexFilePath);
```

4) For matching, I used knnSearch:

```
Mat queryDesc, indicesResult, distsResults;
fIndex.knnSearch(queryDesc, indicesResult, distsResults, 1);
```

But nothing happens. Only "no source available for..." exception occurs. I think I couldn't implement Flann in OpenCV.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, OpenCV 2.4.10, Eclipse CDT+.

Please help me...

Comment: I believe this error is Eclipse telling you it cannot find the source file for debugging (such as if you are stepping through the program). This is because you just have the OpenCV library, not the source code (or at least no reference to it in Eclipse). It has nothing to do with the actual code you have written. The problem is probably to do with how you are using the index -- are there any other error messages? At what point does it actually fail?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as i mentioned before, when i run the code, nothing happens. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. Let me reply my own question :)

1) I extracted SURF features from train images and concatenated all. Then saved descriptors and flann index like this:

```
 Index flannIndex;
 Mat indexDescriptors;
 IndexParams indexParams;
 indexParams = *new KMeansIndexParams();
 flannIndex = *new Index(indexDescriptors, indexParams);
 FileStorage fs(descriptorName, FileStorage::WRITE);
 write(fs, "descriptors", indexDescriptors);
 flannIndex.save(indexName);
```

2) I extracted SURF features from query image.

3) I loaded flann index like this:

```
 Index flannIndexSaved;
 IndexParams indexParamsSaved;
 Mat indexMat;
 indexMat = Mat(Size(64, sampleSize), CV_32F);
 FileStorage fs(yamlFile, FileStorage::READ);
 fs["descriptors"] >> indexMat;
 indexParamsSaved = *new SavedIndexParams(indexFilePath);
 flannIndexSaved = *new Index(indexMat, indexParamsSaved);
```

4) For matching, I used knnSearch:

```
 Mat queryDesc, indicesResult, distsResults;
 flannIndexSaved.knnSearch(queryDesc, indicesResult, distsResults, 1);
```

This works fine :)